# how to put a breakpoint inside a function if it's called through a specific function

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

There are 3 functions: f1, f2, f3:

```
void f1()
{
   f3();
}

void f2()
{
   f3();
}

void f3()
{
   ....
}
```

I want to put a breakpoint somewhere inside f3, but only if f3 was called from f1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to set a breakpoint in gdb that is conditional on the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336403/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-gdb-that-is-conditional-on-the-call-stac).

Comment: Also related:  [GDB break on exception thrown when called from specific function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765176/gdb-break-on-exception-thrown-when-called-from-specific-function). With a recent version of gdb, you can do `b f3 if $_caller_is("f1")`

Comment: And documentation for above function(s) is available at https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to set a breakpoint in gdb that is conditional on the call stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336403/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-gdb-that-is-conditional-on-the-call-stac)

Answer (score 1):

A solution among others consists of setting a conditional breakpoint. the call of f3 is identified by `int boolean`

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int boolean =0;

void f3()
{

}

void f2()
{
    boolean = 1;
    f3();
}

void f1()
{
    boolean = 0;
    f3();
}


int main()
{

    f2();
    f1();
    f2();
    f1();   

    return 0;
}
```

In gdb to set a break in f3 only if you come from f2

```
(gdb)b f3 if boolean==1
```